# Event delegation or multiple listeners for elements that functions differently from each other

Tags: javascript

In most examples of event delegation, I read from multiple sites, I only see the example for `ul/li`. In that case, where every click just does the same thing, only requiring a different id, event delegation is no doubt better.

Will it still be the case if i have one huge eventlistener filled with:

```
if (event.target.id == "this") {
 doThis();
},
if (event.target.id == "that") {
 doThat();
}
```

and so on.. let's say 100 different buttons each having 10-15 different lines of code? Is it better to just assign different event listeners for each button?

Comment: If each button has different logic, then yes, it would make more sense to attach different event listeners for each one, but if some of them use the same logic, you would be better served giving those buttons a common class and then adding the event listener to that class type using the logic that is common to that button group.

Comment: That was fast. Thanks a lot. I was hoping to make one huge controller for a text based game. Nvm i guess.

Comment: What do you mean by one huge controller? If all the buttons are on the same page, then you would still use the same controller.

Comment: well, basically, i was thinking of just adding an event listener on the main element (the huge controller), generate/delete different pages based on button clicks delegated to that one event listener, controlling all of that on one huge function.

Comment: Part of programming is breaking things down into small problems to solve a large problem, how readable would your code be if you crammed everything into one function? How easy would it be to find bugs and maintain your code if it is all crammed into one function? I believe if you break things down into smaller functions which serve a specific purpose you will find maintaining and debugging alot easier in the end.